# Errors while submitting app built with travis to Apple store with App Loader

Tags: ios, react-native, travis-ci, xcode7.3

I'm trying to submit my iOS app built with travis-ci to the App Store, but for some reason I keep receiving this errors:

`ERROR ITMS-90166: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'com.apple.dt.xctestSymbolicator' for executable 'Payload/xxxx.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XPCServices/xctestSymbolicator.xpc/xctestSymbolicator'.""
ERROR ITMS-90179: "Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/xxxx.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XPCServices/xctestSymbolicator.xpc/xctestSymbolicator' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile."
ERROR ITMS-90166: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'com.apple.dt.XCUIRecorderService' for executable 'Payload/xxxx.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XPCServices/XCUIRecorderService.xpc/XCUIRecorderService'.""
ERROR ITMS-90179: "Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/xxxx.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XPCServices/XCUIRecorderService.xpc/XCUIRecorderService' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile."
ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'xxxx.app/PlugIns/xxxx.xctest/xxxx' is not permitted. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
ERROR ITMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle xxxx.app/Frameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework is invalid. The minimum value is 8.0"
ERROR ITMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle xxxx.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework is invalid. The minimum value is 8.0"
ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."`

The app was built with xcode7.3 on travis. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup proper certificate and provision profile in your xCode then try to build application.